# Interval addition onto date

Tags: mysql, postgresql, date

I'm going to attempt to explain the logic and hopefully someone can understand and help me.

Effectively I'm looking for people within my database that have stopped transacting within the first 120 days of first creating their account, but have been inactive for 120 days since their last transaction.

Basically if someone transacts for 120 days and then stops and 3 years later they transact again, I need them to fall into this list. So using `max(transaction.created_at)` isn't going to work.

Hopefully I've explained myself correctly.

Comment: whenever any transaction occurs, are you storing the date of the transaction??

Comment: Please add table structure.

Comment: Isn't this a simple order by created_at desc limit 1 offset 1?

Comment: mysql postgresql - which?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL. Yes, a date is stored in the transaction table and when a customer creates an account, that date is stored too.

Transaction.created_at is stored date, transaction.id is the identifier, customer.id is the identifier, customer.created_at is the creation of account date.

Sorry. I don't know how to cost code or anything complex in these comment sections.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a log of the type

```
table transaction
    user; Timestamp
```

first step is sorting the correct sequence

```
select t.*, 
@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
from transaction t 
JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
order by user, timestamp
```

result

```
user, timestamp, row_id
1       t1           1
1       t1+x         2
...
```

next step is to join consecutive actions by the same user

```
select * from
    (select t.*, 
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
    from transaction t 
    JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
    order by user, timestamp) a
inner join
    (select t.*, 
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
    from transaction t 
    JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
    order by user, timestamp)b
on a.user=b.user and a.row_id=b.row_id-1
```

Result:

```
user timestamp row user timestamp row
 1      t1      1    1     t1+x    2
 2      t1+x    2    1    t1+x+x2  3
...
```

now you just need to filter by time span between events

```
 select * from
        (select t.*, 
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
        from transaction t 
        JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
        order by user, timestamp) a
    inner join
        (select t.*, 
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
        from transaction t 
        JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
        order by user, timestamp)b
    on a.user=b.user and a.row_id=b.row_id+1
WHERE datediff(b.timestamp, a.timestamp)>120
```

now you have a lsit of users that had a break longer than 120 days between transactions
if you need this to happen within first few days from creating an acc, just add `where user in(select user from .... where datediff(min(timestamp, creation_Date)<120)` or do an inner join on user_id to filter by that subquery

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I'm clearly waaaaaaaay behind you cause i'm struggling to understand this entire thing. Sorry if this sounds stupid, but what exactly is "@curRow"?

Comment: I keep getting multiple errors in syntax with this code. The ":" after @curRow gives me an error and after the JOIN (Select ...) line is there another syntax error.

Comment: the second currow query works on mysql, not on postgres. Postgres has row_number() if i recall correctly, so your subqueries woudl look like "select t.*, row_number() from table order by user, timestamp" You did not mention which db you were using, i gave you the solution for the one that woudl be complicated :D

Comment: @currow is a set variable